# Can the discharge when plugging a laptop to a power outlet can do any harm?

Tags: power-supply, ac, switch-mode-power-supply

In [this question](https://superuser.com/q/418779/162491) the OP ask if (s)he should connect a power source into a power outlet first or into the laptop first. While the question has been closed, i think there is a very valid point to consider:

When I plug a laptop power adapter into the laptop first and only then into a power outlet, there is a big, visible and audiable discharge. I've been using several power sources and they all behave the same.

Can this discharge be harmful in any way? For example, can it overload the power source or damage the electrical contacts or the outlet? Or even get transferred through the power source to the laptop?

Returning back to the linked question: For many years I've been following the general principle to first plug a power source into a device and then to the power outlet, because the power source should shield the device from any jitter caused by plugging it in. (However I'm not a specialist and this could be completely wrong.) But seeing and hearing this discharge every time makes me a bit uneasy.

Comment: Do you observe the discharge if the power adapter is not plugged into the laptop?

Comment: @DaveTweed No, without the laptop it doesn't occur.

Comment: The laptop and adaptor will have a slightly easier life if you first connect the laptop to the adaptor then to the mains as if you do it the other way round the adaptor will have its output capacitors fully charged and these will try to charge the input capacitance of the laptop.  In effect this current is only limited by the capacitor ESR.  However, If its designed correctly both the laptop and adaptor should be able to tolerate either way round without damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spark is just the capacitor in the input stage after the rectifier charging up. That is common for a switching power supply, unless the designer put extra effort towards limiting that inrush current.

This can not overload the power supply, it just charges up to normal operating conditions. The input capacitor can't get more voltage than the outlet provides. Can the spark erode the contacts? Maybe, I don't know (these aren't exactly flimsy contacts), but my feeling is that you would face mechanical failure from all the plugging long before that could even become a concern.

The reason that you don't see and hear a spark without the laptop connected could simply be that it is too short and weak when it is only charging that capacitor. The connected laptop, on the other hand, might immediately draw enough current from the outlet through the supply to maintain the spark until the plug is fully connected.

Comment: I'm curious, why the spark doesn't happen when the power supply isn't connected to the laptop?

Comment: @PetrPudlák I added a possible explanation to my answer.